# Only allow self reference to a model that has a reference to the same owner

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have the following data model:

```
public class Bubble
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection <Level> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Level
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BubbleId { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Bubble Bubble { get; set; }

    public Level Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Level> Children { get; set; }
}
```

I want to store multiple sets of hierarchical data.
Each set is owned by a bubble that contains levels (nodes).
A level can either have it's self reference (parent) set to null (head of tree) or another level (sub node of parent) .

Now my problem is, that technically a level can have a parent (self reference) that does belong to another bubble. That should be impossible.

How can i make sure, that only levels with the same BubbleId FK can be assigned as a parent?

Comment: Make `Id` and `BubbleId` a composite primary key.

Comment: Just tested it, i can still asign a Level with another BubbleId. 
I added a optional ParentBubbleId to the Level entity and made a composit key from Id and BubbleId. Was that wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`BubbleId` should be part of `Level`'s primary key, so that other levels referring to it will be guaranteed to have the same `BubbleId`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Level>()
        .HasKey(l => new { l.Id, l.BubbleId });
    modelBuilder.Entity<Level>()
        .Property(l => l.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Level>()
        .HasMany(l => l.Children)
        .WithOptional(l => l.Parent)
        .HasForeignKey(l => new { l.ParentId, l.BubbleId });
}
```